# How to boxplot data after different column values in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, boxplot

I have a dataframe like this:

```
    Country     Year      Column1    Column2
1   Guatemala   1999        5           1
4   Mexico      2000        1           3
5   Mexico      2000        2           2
6   Mexico      2000        2           1
8   Guatemala   2000        3           2
11  Guatemala   2003        4           3
12  Guatemala   2003        6           4
13  Guatemala   2003        5           5
```

What I want to make is a boxplot for each group in `Country`, displaying a number of boxes corresponding to the number of unique values in `Years`. These boxes should represent the values in `Column2`.

I group the data and get boxplots like this:

```
df1=df.groupby('Origin').boxplot(column='Column2', subplots=True)
```

That gives me a boxplot for each Country, but with just one plot in it, representing all the values from that group, not separated by years. How can I get a box for each unique value in `year`, representing the values in Column2 in my code?

Comment: Have you seen [seaborn's boxplot](https://stanford.edu/~mwaskom/software/seaborn/generated/seaborn.boxplot.html)? It seems like it would do exactly what you want.

Comment: Yes, that looks like it! I did not know the module, thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use the [seaborn](https://stanford.edu/~mwaskom/software/seaborn/) package, in particular combining the [FacetGrid](https://stanford.edu/~mwaskom/software/seaborn/tutorial/axis_grids.html) with [boxplot](https://stanford.edu/~mwaskom/software/seaborn/generated/seaborn.boxplot.html).
For your situation, the code might look like this:

```
import seaborn as sns
g = sns.FacetGrid(df, col="Country", sharex=False)
g.map(sns.boxplot, 'Year', 'Column2')
```

Edit: this is what I get for your data above:
[image]

Comment: Really neat module! However when I run the code provided above, I get boxplots for every unique country in my `Country`column (which is what I want), but they only have one box of one `Year`...When I do it without the `FacetGrid` I get all boxes for all years in one plot, but not divided by origin (logically).

Comment: It looks like the axis limits aren't being set. Try the code in the edit above.

Comment: Awesome, now it works. Is there a way to display the `Year` values on the x axis in order from the lowest to highest? I did not find that in the manual yet..But thank you, good answer, cool new module!

Comment: Edit – use ``sharex=False`` to make the axes work correctly. This also obviates the need for ``ax.axis('tight')``. See edited code above.

Comment: Now it works beautifully for me as well! The values on the x-axis are not in order, as they are mixed in my original df. Can you recommend a good tutorial for seaborn? It looks really worth learning!

Comment: To make sure the columns stay in order, convert them to categorical: ``df['Year'] = df['Year'].astype('category')`` For a seaborn tutorial, I'd recommend poking through the examples on the website. You might also like this preview section from my book: https://www.oreilly.com/learning/data-visualization-with-seaborn